# Trigger image transition by hovering over a text link

Tags: css, image, hover, hyperlink, transition

OK, I'm a complete rookie and have gleemed the coding I have so far from various resources online and adapted it to suit my needs, so be gentle :P

Basically, I have a nice CSS transition happening when hovering over an image. However, I want to put a text link beneath said image, that will trigger the same image transition when you hover over the text link. Is this possible? I've been searching for a result for some time now and still not cracked this one!

```
CSS

a.home:link {color:#040404; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;   font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace; font-size:18px;}
a.home:visited {color:#040404; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace; font-size:18px;}
a.home:hover {color:#E5712C; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace; font-size:18px;}
a.home:active {color:#5F5F5F; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace; font-size:18px;}



#crossfade
{
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: solid 2px #5f5f5f;
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
}

#crossfade img
{
position:absolute;
left:0;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#crossfade img.top:hover {
opacity:0;
}


HTML

<div id="crossfade">
<img class="bottom" src="http://www.officialdrivingtheory.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/TheoryTest-question.jpg"><a href="http://www.livingthai.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/How-to-test-your-Thai-Language-ability.jpg"</a>
<img class="top" src="http://www.dandybooksellers.com/acatalog/PracticalTest.jpg"/><a href="http://www.livingthai.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/How-to-test-your-Thai-Language-ability.jpg"</a>

</div></br>
<a class ="home" href="http://www.livingthai.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/How-to-test-your-Thai-Language-ability.jpg">TESTING</a>
```

You can see what I'm trying to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/WxVE4/1/

I've just used placeholder images and links for now as my site isn't published yet.

Oh, and if anyone can tell me how to align the text link nice and centrally beneath the image then that's extra brownie points :D

Comment: I don't think you can do this without JavaScript; is that an option?

Comment: Yes, I can use javascript if needs be. SilveBlade's answer helped get closer to my goal using javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

For aligning the link to center, you can wrap the whole content inside a div and make the div sytle to

```
{ display: inline-block; text-align: center; }
```

If you could use javascipt, then you might be able to do effect you need,

```
document.getElementsByClassName('home')[0].onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('top')[0].style.opacity = 0;
}

document.getElementsByClassName('home')[0].onmouseout = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('top')[0].style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/WxVE4/2/

Comment: Thanks SilverBlade! This could work a treat, however I've noticed that once you hover over the text-link, hovering over the image no longer transitions it :(  Any ideas why this happens? I'm trying to solve it too.